# jQuery fader for two contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I want to fade two contents the same time on one page by clicking a teaser:
e.g. click on #teaser2 the contents in #backstage2 and #content2 are fading in the same time.

look at my html

```
<!-- backstage content is in a separate div -->
<div id="backstage">
     <div id="bigpicture1"> 
        <img src="img1.jpg" width="800" height="600" /> 
    </div> 
    <div id="bigpicture2"> 
        <img src="img2.jpg" width="800" height="600" /> 
    </div> 
    <div id="bigpicture3"> 
        <img src="img3.jpg" width="800" height="600" /> 
    </div>   
</div>

<!-- stage content is also in a separate div -->
<div id="stage"> 
    <div id="content1"> 
        <h2>Loremipsum 1</h2> 
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend.<a href="#">mehr ...</a></p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content2"> 
        <h2>Loremipsum 2</h2> 
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend.<a href="#">mehr ...</a></p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content3"> 
        <h2>Loremipsum 3</h2> 
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend.<a href="#">mehr ...</a></p> 
    </div>   
</div> 

<!-- teasers are in a separate div -->
<div id="teaser"> 
    <ul> 
        <li id="teaser1"><img src="img1_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></li> 
        <li id="teaser2"><img src="img2_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></li> 
        <li id="teaser3"><img src="img3_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

I found here "http://www.brightyoursite.com/blog/2010/01/23/nice-jquery-content-slider/" some nice code but works only with one content-DIV...
Hope you understand "german-style" english - thanks for your help

Ottmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't use suSlider plugin, I think I got the same results as you are looking for but just using jQuery and jQueryUI:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/K9jNP/

Comment: Yippie! Thank you! Now: How to hide the non-shown elements, this html will be automatically generated - so you will have sometimes more contents...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#backstage2 , #content2").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery('#teaser2').bind('click', function() {
 jQuery('#backstage2 , #content2').fadeOut();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw2eV/)**

Comment: thank you for your help - I want to use a function for automatically generated code like you can see in the HTML-code above. have you seen the code-example on [link]http://www.brightyoursite.com/blog/2010/01/23/nice-jquery-content-slider/[/link]. Is it possible to modify this or do you some others