# jQuery fadein/fadeout on hover causes window bounce

Tags: jquery, fadein

Just started using fadein/fadeout - it's functioning but with problems. I have a set of div's containing links (ie '#linki'). The id of each 'link' div is targetted so that hover on/off on the link text causes images/text in a second set of stacked div's (ie '#webshoti') to undergo fadein + fadeout response. So basically my page code holds a set of 10 #link div's (inside 'linkWrapper' div), 10 #webshot div's (all occupying the same position inside 'webshots' div) and 10 instances of the jQuery script:

eg of html for #link div:

```
<div class="linkList1"><a href="http://www.fmc.gov.au/">Federal Magistrates Court</a></div>
```

eg of #webshot div:

```
#webshot1{
position:absolute;
right:30px;
width:500px;
height:322px;
display:none;
```

eg of jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
$('.linkList1').mouseenter(
function(){
$('#webshotText').fadeOut(200, function(){
$('#webshot1').fadeIn(450);
});
}
);
$('.linkList1').mouseleave(
function(){
$('#webshot1').fadeOut(20);
}
);
});
```

(note that #webshotText is displayed on page load, until any of the #link div's are hovered)

This web page can be viewed [HERE](http://lawyer.kirkfx.com/links.html)

The problem: 
(1.) hovering down the list of 'link' divs causes window to jump (hey look - it's jQuery Bounce! Doh). 
  (2.) in some cases the image in #webshot which is targetted by currently hovered #link appears to load while the previously targetted #webshot image is still unloading, causing incoming image to be (momentarily) stacked under bottom edge of outgoing image.

I tried setting the mouseout>fadeout to a short time (was 200ms) but no change. I've applied a jQuery image preloader in code but no change. Happens in windows/FF4 and IE8

Any suggestions? Thanks heaps, Kirk
(** bonus points if there's any way I could employ array scripting to avoid need for 10 instances of jQuery script!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/K9jNP/) (made to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272725/jquery-fader-for-two-contents/5273048#5273048) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272725/jquery-fader-for-two-contents/)) can help:

The idea is to:

1. Draw everything you need with regular HTML
2. Absolute position every image you want to fade-in / fade-out
3. Apply fade effects without worrying of stacking effect (they are now absolute-positioned!).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Marcos - yes, had to convert the listLink div's to absolute positioning (the webshot images were already absolutely positioned) and all good now. Merci boocow mate! Kirk

Comment: @kirk-tab: glad to know it worked. Please accept the answer as the correct one so the community knows a) that it is already solved and b) how-to solve a similar problem.